# find condition on $a(n)$ such that the $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{a(n)\cdot (n-a(n))}{\log\binom{n}{a(n)}}=+\infty$

Tags: asymptotics, binomial-coefficients

I met the following problem in my research but I don't know how to deal with it:

What is the condition on $a(n)$ such that $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{a(n)\cdot (n-a(n))}{\log\binom{n}{a(n)}}=+\infty$$

note that $a$ can be (no neccessary) function on $n$ thus $\binom{n}{a}$ is $\binom{n}{a(n)}$

Example. If $a(n)=n/2$ then this condition is satisfied.

Comment: Is $\binom{n}{a}=\binom{n}{a(n)}$?

Comment: Hello. Can you explain why the condition is satisfied if $a(n) = n/2$? Isn't the limit finite because of the bound [$\binom{2n}n \ge 4^n/(2n + 1)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_binomial_coefficient#Asymptotic_growth)? Is $\binom na$ indeed a binomial coefficient?

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen I don't see the issue here (your deduction is different from mine), but here is my analysis, not sure whether it is correct: since $\binom{n}{n/2}\sim \frac{2^n}{\sqrt{\frac{n}{2}\pi}}$ then the original formula is $\sim\frac{n^2/4}{n\log 2-\log(\sqrt{n\pi/2})}$ thus it tends to infinity because the nominator increases faster than the denominator. And yes, $\binom{n}{a}$ is binomial coefficient.

Comment: Does $a(n-a)$ mean $a$ times $n-a$ or $a$ evaluated at $n-a$? You either write $a$ or $a(n) $ throughout for clarity.

Comment: @Gary sorry for the confusion, it is the product of $a$ and $n-a$.

Comment: Ah, is your numerator supposed to be $a(n) \cdot (n - a(n))$? I think you should probably format it like that to avoid confusion!

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen oh yes, I didn't realize this would create confusion, I will revise

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Bounds_and_asymptotic_formulas should be useful.

Answer (score 1):

Let $s=1/n$ and $r = a/n = a \cdot s  $

We have ([see](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Bounds_and_asymptotic_formulas)) the bound

$$\frac{1}{a \cdot(n-a) }\log \binom{n}{a} \le \frac{n}{a \cdot (n-a) } H(r)= s \frac{H(r)}{r \cdot (1-r)} \tag 1$$

where $H(r)= -r \log r -(1-r)\log (1-r)$ is the binary entropy function. The bound is quite tight (we might add the corresponding lower bound to make it more complete).

We want $(1)$ to tend to zero as $s \to 0$.

Let's assume $r$ has some limit.

If $r$ tends to some value inside $(0,1)$, then we are done.

If $r \to 0$, then the RHS of $(1)$ tends to

$$ - s \log (r) = -s \log s -  s \log a$$

Hence, it's enough to assume $a\ge 1$, and we are also done.

If $r \to 1$ , then the RHS of $(1)$ tends to

$$ - s \log (1-r) = -s \log(1- a s) $$

Again, it's enough to prescribe

$$ a \le n-1 \implies 1-r \ge s $$

Hence, it seems the desired limit is verified practically always. All we are requiring is $0<a<n$ and that $a/n$ has some limit (but I guess this also can be relaxed).